# Preserving results with UNION ALL

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got a query that is created with the UNION ALL keyword. Problem is, when one of the SELECTs returns an empty set, it is discarded. I need it to at least return NULL or an empty row.

I read somewhere if you have a unique index for each SELECT, it will prevent the discard, but it's not working.

Query is created with a loop, so the *date index* (i.e. "2013-Jun") changes, just demonstrating one select.

```
SELECT `products`.`id`, `products`.`ugid`, CONCAT(`products`.`fsg_pre`, `products`.`fsg_suff`) AS `fsg`, `year`, 'Mar' AS `month`, '2012-Mar' AS `index`, `Mar` AS `price`
FROM `prices`
JOIN `products`
ON (`products`.`uuid` = `prices`.`uuid`)
WHERE TRUE
AND `products`.`ugid` = '52777'
AND `products`.`fsg_pre` = 'SU'
AND `products`.`fsg_suff` = '3'
AND `year` = 2012

UNION ALL
[..........]
```

Comment: A SELECT that matches no rows will have zero rows, whether it is being used in a UNION or not. So your challenge is actually to find a query which, when there is no relevant data, creates a row containing NULLs where the data would have been. My bet would be on a LEFT JOIN being involved, possibly with a dummy sub-query that always has one row. If I wasn't so tired, I'd probably have turned this into an answer already.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use LEFT JOIN as suggested by IMSoP like:

```
SELECT `products`.`id`, `products`.`ugid`, CONCAT(`products`.`fsg_pre`,
`products`.`fsg_suff`) AS `fsg`, `year`, 'Mar' AS `month`, '2012-Mar' AS `index`, 
`Mar` AS `price`
 FROM `prices`
 LEFT JOIN `products`
 ON `products`.`uuid` = `prices`.`uuid`
 WHERE `products`.`ugid` = '52777'
 AND `products`.`fsg_pre` = 'SU'
 AND `products`.`fsg_suff` = '3'
 AND `year` = 2012
```

or FULL JOIN to have always a row empty or not.

```
 SELECT `products`.`id`, `products`.`ugid`, CONCAT(`products`.`fsg_pre`,
`products`.`fsg_suff`) AS `fsg`, `year`, 'Mar' AS `month`, '2012-Mar' AS `index`, 
`Mar` AS `price`
 FROM `prices`
 FULL JOIN `products`
 ON `products`.`uuid` = `prices`.`uuid`
 WHERE `products`.`ugid` = '52777'
 AND `products`.`fsg_pre` = 'SU'
 AND `products`.`fsg_suff` = '3'
 AND `year` = 2012
```

See link [here](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) to visually see how JOIN works.